# Django StaticLiveServerTestCase cannot TRUNCATE and FLUSH

Tags: django, postgresql, selenium, tdd, functional-testing

I try to implement TDD using:

1. django version 3.0
2. Selenium version 3.141.0 with chromedriver.exe
3. PgAdmin4 (Postgresql 13.0)

Here is my test code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase


class NewUserTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver.exe")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_success_login(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)

        input_username = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_username')
        input_password = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_password')
        self.assertTrue(input_password.get_attribute('required'))

        input_username.send_keys('onesinus')
        input_password.send_keys('123')
        input_password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

But when the test executed

```
python manage.py test
```

I have two error:

```
1. django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "my_table_name" references "auth_user".
HINT:  Truncate table "my_table_name" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.

2. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mycms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 274, in __call__
    self._post_teardown()
  File "D:\mycms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1009, in _post_teardown
    self._fixture_teardown()
  File "D:\mycms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1041, in _fixture_teardown
    call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False,
  File "D:\mycms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 168, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "D:\mycms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\mycms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\flush.py", line 65, in handle
    raise CommandError(
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Database test_db-staging couldn't be flushed. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the expected database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin sqlflush'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
```

Someone have find this problem before? or someone can help me to solve this?

Is that possible if I use django.test.runner like override teardown_databases method?

I am thinking of changing profession :)

Thank you so much for your response and help! have a nice day!